# Json Data format in Swift

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I get this error

"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."
Below is my code and the multiply ways i tried decoding the json.

```
struct UserProfileAPIResult: Codable {
    let data: [UserProfile]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "results"
    }
}


struct UserProfile: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var usercoverimage: URL
    var userprofileimage: URL
    var userprofilename: String
    var userprofiledesc: String
    let pfm: [ProfileMusic]
    let pfi: [ProfileImages]
    let pfv: [ProfileVideos]
//    var pfm: ProfileMusic
//    var pfi: ProfileImages
//    var pfv: ProfileVideos
//    let pfm: [ProfileMusic]?
//   let pfi: [ProfileImages]?
//    let pfv: [ProfileVideos]?
}

struct ProfileMusic: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String?
    var musicimages: URL?
    var musicfile: URL?
    var musicname: String?
    var musicartistname: String?
    var musicgenre: String?
    var musicshared: String?
    var musicalikes: String?
    var musicdownloaded: String?
    var musiclistens: String?
    var musictext: String?
}

struct ProfileImages: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String?
    var albumimages: URL?
    var abumlikes: String?
    var albumviews: String?
    var albumtext: String?
}

struct ProfileVideos: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String?
    var videoname: String?
    var videoduration: String?
    var videocoverimage: URL?
    var videoartistname: String?
    var videofile: URL?
    var videoreleasedate: String?
    var videoviews: String?
    var videotext: String?
}
```

I am trying to nest the 3 structs inside the main struct and get this error, please any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

This is the printed error after

dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "pfm", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "musicimages", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Invalid URL string.", underlyingError: nil))
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "pfm", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "musicimages", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Invalid URL string.", underlyingError: nil))
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "pfm", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "musicimages", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Invalid URL string.", underlyingError: nil))
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "pfm", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "musicimages", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Invalid URL string.", underlyingError: nil))
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "pfm", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "musicimages", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Invalid URL string.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Print the `error`, not its `localizedDescription`. And *i tried decoding the json*. What JSON?

Comment: The error clearly says that the value for key `musicimages` is not a valid URL representation. Decode `String` Instead.

Comment: @vadian I commented out the ProfileMusic struct and let pfm: [ProfileMusic], after i ran the code everything was good. Is there anyway i could make the profileMusic struct optional because not every user will upload music. I earlier made it optional like this let pfm: [ProfileMusic]? and still had errors.

Comment: I don’t know. It needs more information.

Comment: @vadian Thanks I'll keep trying to fix it, and post an answer when i do. Thanks for your time.